# What's the best way to join an array into a readable list?

Tags: python, join, string

I've got an array listing days of the week:

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']
```

What's the easiest / best way to output it in a human readable format:

```
Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday
```

The best I have is rather ugly:

```
', '.join(days[:-2]+['']) + ' and '.join(days[-2:])
```

Comment: [One example, from Supybot](http://supybot.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=supybot/supybot;a=blob;f=src/utils/str.py;h=c6d801ce772104d03a24a21ccedf06840d579c45;hb=79c7514f1a94b0f1792991a85a8b2fe907cffdb5#l207)

Comment: but are you sure it is the *right* way? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Comment: Putting a comma there or not are both "acceptable practice", so arguing about it is just a distraction, but I never put a comma there and it looks jarringly "wrong" to me (as a native speaker) when people do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is everyone trying to force-fit this into a single expression?

```
def comma_separated(lst):
    """
    >>> comma_separated(['a'])
    'a'
    >>> comma_separated(['a', 'b'])
    'a and b'
    >>> comma_separated(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    'a, b and c'
    """
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    comma_part = ", ".join(lst[:-1])
    return "%s and %s" % (comma_part, lst[-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

And remember, this is specific to English (and aside from "and", probably some other Western languages).  Other languages have entirely different rules.

Comment: I think my ugly example is the one that would pass code golf but I like this one as it seems the most pythonic / explicit compared to the others.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I would do:

```
'%s and %s' % (', '.join(days[:-1]), days[-1])
```

I am not sure it's pretty, but I am not sure it has to be either. :)

Comment: @Ross: A more general but uglier solution would be: `(days + [''])[0] if len(days) <= 1 else '%s and %s' % (', '.join(days[:-1]), days[-1])`.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: your answer below is a more holistic solution.  I wasn't implying that my answer would work for every list, just a "better" way of writing the single expression he used above given the fixed list that was part of his question.
@Ross: you want to use what I wrote as part of a function which takes into consideration the edge case of a single element list.  Glenn's function is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a lambda/function once and then just re-use it.

```
def days(*d):
    ''.join([i + ((n < len(d) - 2 and ', ') or ' and ') for n, i in enumerate(d)])[:-5] + '.'

print days('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday')
>>> Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday.

print days('Monday', 'Tuesday')
>>> Monday and Tuesday.

print days('Monday', 'Tuesday')
>>> Monday.
```

Works for every combination too :)

Comment: You know, if a lambda gets as long as that, it probably makes sense to make it a normal function instead.

Comment: I know... but my there isn't much left over form my brain at this moment... to much coding today...

Answer (score 0):

```
def as_human_readable_list(values: list[str]) -> str:
  """
  >>> as_human_readable_list([])
  ''
  >>> as_human_readable_list(["foo"])
  'foo'
  >>> as_human_readable_list(["foo", "bar"])
  'foo and bar'
  >>> as_human_readable_list(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
  'foo, bar and baz'
  """
  return ', '.join(values[:-2] + [' and '.join(values[-2:])])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you really don't need that second `join()` in your 'best' sample. you can rewrite it this way:

```
', '.join(days[:-1])+' and '+days[-1]
```

personally, i always prefer calling the class method, because i find the syntax closer to the intent:

```
str.join(', ',days[:-1])+' and '+days[-1]
```